# How to write Flexible Search for joined tables in Hybris

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I am trying to get all users which don't have addresses, there is a relation between user and address tables(one to many) and the address has an owner attribute that refers to Users pk. how can I achieve that ??

```
SELECT {u:pk} 
FROM {User AS u 
    LEFT JOIN Address AS a ON {u:pk}={a:owner}} 
WHERE {u:owner} IS NULL
```

I wrote a query which I guess doesn't work correctly

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: FYI, the issue with your query is you check if the owner of the user is null. but you want that to be the address. so the where should be `{a.owner} IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {User} WHERE {pk} not in ({{ SELECT {owner} FROM {Address} WHERE {owner} IS NOT NULL }})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write {a:owner} not {u:owner}.
This query gave me the same result:
SELECT {u:pk} FROM {User AS u LEFT JOIN Address AS a ON {u:pk}={a:owner}} WHERE {a:owner} IS NULL